# (Linux) syntax error: operand expected (error token is "**")

Tags: bash

To calculate $1*$1*$1

```
#!/bin/bash

volume=$1*$1*$1
echo "The volume of the cube is"$volume
```

In terminal, it shows
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjYZI.png)

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Use the _select_ then the _copy_ functionality provided by your OS and then _paste_ the text in the question. Use the `{}` button in the toolbar of the question editor to format it nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(( ))` to evaluate arithmetic expressions in `bash`.

```
volume=$(($1 * $1 * $1))
```

You can also use the `let` command:

```
let volume=$1*$1*$1
```

or you can use `(( ))` to execute an arithmetic statement

```
((volume = $1 * $1 * $1))
```

What you wrote was being treated as a filename wildcard.

You also need to provide an argument to the script, this will be used as `$1`.

```
$ bash testarith.sh 5
The volume of the cube is 125
```

Comment: It still keeps saying syntax error: operand expected (error token is "**") - I typed your all solutions... I cannot figure out why

Comment: Your script requires an argument, the number to be multiplied.

Comment: ohh thank you so much I finally realized what was wrong! thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Bash also provides a power arithmetic operator `**`: `volume=$(($1**3))`